# No error message shown when validating array input field using Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

No errors shown. Doesn't matter what I put in input field.

Here is my blade file.

```html
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="names[]"/>
  @if($errors->has('names'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('names') }}</strong>
    </span>
  @endif
```

Here is my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
      'names.*' => 'required|exists:users,name',
  ]);
}
```

Comment: use `unique` method to try

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this. I used this type of my own.

```
<div class="{{'form-group required'.$errors->first('title',' has-error')}}">
     <label>Title</label>
     <input type="text" name="title[]" class="form-control" required>
     <div class="text-danger">{{$errors->has('title') ? $errors->first('title') : ''}}</div>
</div>
```

IN my controller I use like this.

```
$request->validate([
    'title'    => ['required','array'],
    'title.*'  => ['required','unique:galleries','min:5'],
]);
```

And it gives me the error like this

> The title must be a string.
>
> The title must be at least 5 characters.

Comment: This gives me names must be a string.

Comment: I also must have unique:users,name. Otherwise I got an error in Laravel.

Comment: If I put Adam,Anna in input field I got this error message The selected names is invalid.I know Adam and Anna exists in the users table. I want to be able to put severel names in input field seperated by comma.

Comment: If you want to show multiple name with comma separated in validation message then I think you can solve by writing custom validation rule

Comment: I already tried that. I looped through the values and used explode, but I could't figure out how to compare the vaules with the values in the users table. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

we need to validate names as array first then we can validate each attribute which is inside array.

```
$request->validate([
  'names' => 'required|array',
  'names.*' =>'required|exists:users,name'
]);
```

Comment: No errors shown here either. Empty field show no errors.